# Rails AJAX: execute js.erb file when user types URL in browser bar

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

My problem is as follows: I have a rails app where all the links are `:remote => true`. So all the content is loaded with AJAX, while some of the page elements will only load once. So a link to `articles#index` will go through `articles.js.erb`, **execute some functions**, and render the content. Here's an example of `articles.js.erb`:

```
centerMiddleMenu();
$("#content-container").html('<%= j(render("articles"))%>');
setStudioContentWidth();
setContentWidth();

pageurl = "/thestudio/articles";

if(pageurl!=window.location){
  window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
}
```

What happens here: I set the width on some elements based on the available content, and change the URL to display: `domain.com/articles`. The problem however is that the functions above don't seem to execute when the user types in the URL (`domain.com/articles`) directly. This is problem because if someone shares a link and the other guy visits it, the site doesn't look good because the width of the content isn't properly set.

I would like to know if I can have Rails use `article.js.erb` even when someone types the URL in the browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if something is not clear, English is not my native language ;)

Comment: Sounds it's related to content type. When the page is requested it sends appropriate header (i guess something like javascript) which makes the `articles.js.erb` to execute. But when someone hits the URl directly, it's executing html templates (`articles.html.erb`). You can use `render` method explicitly to render `*.js*` templates. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help! Reading that article I figured I just needed to do `render 'articles.js.erb'` at the end of the action. However this produces the following error: `Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.` It seems I have to disable `protect_from_forgery` for every URL, and I'm reluctant to do this for the entire application...

Comment: Yes, there are multiple way of solving this and the way you did was one of them. As of CSRF token, you can disable it but that's not recommended. You should be able to find a great amount of answers for it's solution on SO.

Answer (score 0):

for every action call on a controller,there has be the acceptable type set...for example..refer [respond_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to)

**html call(entering url in browser)** -use `index.html.erb`

**js call(ajax call/submit)**- use `index.js.erb`

**json call(using tokeninput or other js to fetch)**- use `format.json { render json: @users}`

===================
**OR**-to handle all ====================

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js {"show"}
  format.json { render json: @users }
  format.xml @users.to_xml
end
```